# Finding tangent line of curve that pass through the origin

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions, tangent-line

I am trying to find the equation of tangent line of the curve that pass through the origin. The equation of the curve is  **y = tanh(×)**. 
I am solving this in hopes of solving the critical value of  positive constant **c** for which **cx = tanh(x)** has nontrivial solutions

Answer (score 0):

Derivative of $\tanh(x)$ simply is $sech^{2}x$, with slope$=1$ at origin. The tangent has equation.

$$ y= x $$

For $c<1$  the second equation gives  two roots as anti-symmetric solutions found by direct substitution.

If you are trying to find points of intersection in graphs of

$$ y=cx, \quad y= \tanh x $$

then there is no need at all to worry about slope at origin.

Did you try to solve numerically using Newton-Raphson iteration?